# Excel VBA custom function works in Debug.Print but not in worksheet (gives incorrect answers)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a workbook with several sheets, each of which has the same table/layout in it. New sheets get added periodically and old ones deleted.

I want to count how many times a specific string occurs in a specific column (always the same column letter), across *all* of the sheets put together. That's easy to do with a COUNTIFS + COUNTIFS + etc., but I don't want to have to keep updating my COUNTIFS formulas every time I add or remove sheets. I wrote a function to check all the sheets whose names are stored in an array, so all I'll have to do is update that one array.

Public items declared before the function:

```
' Used by function checkDuplicates
' Array to hold names of tabs in use within workbook
' NOTE: Need to update within the function when sheets are added/deleted
    Public yearArr As Variant
' Location of column to check
    Const myCol As String = "H:H"
```

The function itself:

```
Function checkDuplicates(myString As String) As Integer

' Update this when sheets are added or deleted
yearArr = Array("2018", "2019", "2020", "2021")

' Year referenced by worksheet tabs 
' Will reference the contents of yearArr
Dim yearSheet As Variant

' Integers to hold our running totals
Dim bigTotal As Integer
Dim loopTotal As Integer
' Reset them at the start of each function run (probably not necessary but hey)
bigTotal = 0
loopTotal = 0

' Loop through all sheets and count

For Each yearSheet In yearArr
    ' Select a specific sheet
    Debug.Print "This yearSheet is " & yearSheet
    Sheets(yearSheet).Select
    ' Count how many instances of 'myString' in 'myCol' column
    loopTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(myCol), myString)
    Debug.Print "loopTotal is now " & loopTotal
    ' Add the total from this loop onto the running total
    Debug.Print "bigTotal is now " & bigTotal
    bigTotal = bigTotal + loopTotal
    Debug.Print "At the end of loop " & yearSheet & ", bigTotal is finally " & bigTotal
    
Next yearSheet

' Output final total
checkDuplicates = bigTotal
Debug.Print "Final output is " & checkDuplicates

End Function
```

An example output from the Immediate Window:

```
This yearSheet is 2018
loopTotal is now 40
logTotal is now 0
At the end of loop 2018, logTotal is finally 40
This yearSheet is 2019
loopTotal is now 9
logTotal is now 40
At the end of loop 2019, logTotal is finally 49
This yearSheet is 2020
loopTotal is now 19
logTotal is now 49
At the end of loop 2020, logTotal is finally 68
This yearSheet is 2021
loopTotal is now 0
logTotal is now 68
At the end of loop 2021, logTotal is finally 68
Final output is 68
```

Works beautifully! However, using =functionCheckDuplicates("blah") in a cell returns 0 instead of 68! I tried with another 'blah' that should return 2 (and does in the Immediate Window) and the function returned 4 in the cell! It's not even consistently incorrect in a way that I can see.

What am I doing that's stupid?

Answer (score 2):

I found a formula-based answer! I made a table containing a list of all the other table names I wanted to check, and then saved the list as a named range. Now I can stick this formula in a cell:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(listActive&"[specific column name]"),"Blah"))
```

Where 'listActive' is the named range containing all the table names.

This page helped: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2541-excel-countif-across-multiple-worksheets.html

I was massively overthinking it in my original question. I'd still appreciate other answers/thoughts to increase my knowledge of custom functions and what they can and can't do.